# Understanding third party login stategy

Tags: node.js, google-signin

I am trying to understand the google login system, this is what I have understood, please help me with a doubt here.
I have 2 different server for FE & BE.
According to some tuts, I have to provide a callback to the google console which will redirect the user after verification, here I am giving the front end url, as if backend url  is giving  my Fe will not gonna aware of this.

Ques:- As docs the redirect url will give me user profile, since it is coming to front-end I need to send it to my Backend, here I have to make simple http request, `now this request can be made by any person as because I don't have any means to verify like token and all...`?
what would you do here and what am i doing wrong.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is correct, you can have a look at this section of the docs, https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth you will be needed to send the token, given by the Google and later you can verify the correctness of same by querying.
Thanks.